# 2つのnullableなプロパティが同時にnullにならない場合の型定義

Tags: typescript

TypeScriptの型定義に関する質問です。

ここに両者ともnullableなプロパティを持ったクラスがあったとします。

```
class Example {
  foo: string | null;
  bar: string | null;
}
```

このクラスでは、`foo` と `bar` が同時に `null` になることはなく、また逆に同時に `string` 型になることはあるとします。

しかしこの型定義だと、例えば以下のようなコードを記述すると当然 `string` 型に確定することはなく、エラーとなります。

```
const str: string = <Example>.foo ?? <Example>.bar;
```

この問題を解決するために、両プロパティがnullableでありつつも、同時に `null` とはならない型を定義したいのですが、解決方法が見つけられません。

もちろん、どちらかがnullableではない新しいクラスを2つ用意し、`is～` のような型アサーション関数(?)でクラスを振り分ける方法もあるかと思いますが、できれば他の方法で実現できればと思っています。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

同じ意図の質問が

- [Check that at least one interface member is non-null in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57572437/4506703)

にあるようです。

また、型エイリアスが利用可能であれば、

- [How to create a Partial-like that requires a single property to be set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48244432/4506703)

の回答がスマートかと考えます。

(TypeScriptに習熟していないのでより良い書き方があるかも知れませんが、)こんな感じになるかと思います:

```js
type Draft<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | null };
type AtLeastOne<T, U = { [K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }> = Draft<T> & U[keyof U];

type FullExampleType = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};

type ExampleType = AtLeastOne<FullExampleType>;

const v1: ExampleType = { foo: "foo_val", bar: "bar_val" }; // OK
const v2: ExampleType = { foo: "foo_val", bar: null }; // OK
const v3: ExampleType = { foo: null, bar: "bar_val" }; // OK
const v4: ExampleType = { foo: null, bar: null }; // NG
```

([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgQwGbADwBUB8UC8UDeUA2gNJQCWAdlANYQgD2SU6AugFwumtQA+UlAK4AbYVAC+AbgBQoSFACCwADIQEAZ2AB5ShAwAaKAFVcBYmSq16TFhygAFcgGMaBqCWzjseeMjRYoADJjIjpGZiNWGVlwaAAxEWEAUQAPBABbMGEIdFjTfGkoKCQGBk5NOCoAcxkigCMEOHLgSsoa6SlpGPlUjKycvLwlVQ1tXVQE0V7M7NzITGinBkpNKAA3AEZOaf656DxCErKoACIjgH01hGETwwam0-vL65OJSSgAeg+oLRJpJZWwHWACZtmkZgN5AdiqVOGdSs8bndGpwhKI3p9vr9-stVmsAMxgvqzQZmI6oxLIh4nJ5XG4Yr4-P4AvEAFiJEL2+RhxzRwipFPRUkxUAAcgBxaRAA))

---

コメントにある、 "他にもプロパティやメソッドが実装されている" については、[交差(intersection)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces)で対応できるかと考えます。

```
type AllProps = {
  baz: string;
} & ExampleType;

const v5: AllProps = { foo: null, bar: null, baz: "baz_val" }; // NG
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

件の問題をほぼ解決できる策ではありますが、実際には他にもプロパティやメソッドが実装されているクラスであることと、型定義の複雑さを踏まえると、他の方法もまだ模索したいなと考えております。

Answer (score 0):

classの2つのプロパティを型レベルで制御するのは（おそらく）至難の業なので、オブジェクトのプロパティとして持つ方法として１つ紹介します。

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiEIHkB2AbROAXjgG8AoOOAM0wC44BnGKASxwHMBuSuAIwCGUBjgCuePDwC+PcqEiwEyVACEhuAsTK9aEEeMm9Bwpi3bdyM8nPDR4SFOkxqoWilV0NmbTjyrGvM19LWXk7JUdcYCxqLQxsfEIAHzgXDWSnCBdQ20UAYzwBRkY4AFEQAQBbMDxUdzgwUT48VjzTARhgBiiYt14qD3o4MQkAGn6BgLgAImNp8aorKWs8iBxmOHZmARw81BIcYAB3Morq2oAKAEpZVliLrZgdvYA6bc6X42IDgyvtAc26yeu2AbyeH10cAA9FDTD4OJZrHc4A8gc9Qe9QZCiDjhr9-gNHuiwR1QV8YXDzIjyMjUdsQSSPl8cT8JHAAGTswH016Yl7Y3EjPB-epUIkMvnk2GHABuwCgE3FvPBWMw0OlwDlCuWQA)

```
export type FooOnly = {
  foo: string;
  bar: null;
};

export type BarOnly = {
  foo: null;
  bar: string;
};

export type FooBar = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};

export type OneOf = FooOnly | BarOnly | FooBar;

export class Example {
  public state: OneOf = {
    foo: null,
    bar: "bar",
  };
}

const instance = new Example();

if (instance.state.bar == null) {
  instance.state.foo; // string
}

if (instance.state.foo === null) {
  instance.state.bar; // string
}

if (instance.state.bar === null && instance.state.foo === null) {
  instance.state.bar; // never
  instance.state.foo; // never
}
```

classのmember変数としてバラバラに持つと、型レベルで制御できない部分（内部参照など）で値を変更できてしまうため、型の恩恵を受けることができなくなります。